# Cannot truncate the file to compact it c++

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to compact a file with deleted records, I intend to save the file in temporary character array, then open a new file or truncate the existent one to write the temporary character array without deleted records, this is the code

```
void compact(fstream &file)
{
    header = -1;
    file.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(2, ios::beg);    ///Why seek from 0 not working, it's must to seek from 2
    char temp[fileSize];    ///Is it better to declare this char dynamically ?
    file.read(temp, fileSize);

    cout << "temp size = " << strlen(temp) << endl;
    cout <<  "filesize = "<<  fileSize << endl;
    cout << temp << endl;

    file.close();

    fstream outfile("newfile.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
    outfile.seekp(0, ios::beg);
    outfile.write((char*)& header, sizeof(header));
    for(int i = 0 ; i<strlen(temp) ; i++)
    {
        if(temp[i] == '*')
        {
            i+=recordSize -1 ;
        }
        else
            file.write((char*)&temp[i], 1);
    }
}
```

neither opening a new file nor opening an existent one works, I think this line cause the problem `fstream outfile("newfile.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);`
it cause a very strange logic to me; I'm printing the temp after load the file into it and it's printed normally, once he reach the mentioned line it changes the temp !, I try to comment this line then temp again is printed normaly. 
Simply how can I open a new file or truncate an existent one to store temp in it without deleted record?

Comment: ***///Is it better to declare this char dynamically ?*** Yes one reason is standard `c++` requires an array to have a fixed compile time constant size. VLAs are illegal in standard `c++` Also even for compilers supporting this non-standard extension there is a limit to the size of the allocation. Usually it is allocated on the stack which is by default 10MB on linux or 1 MB on windows.

Comment: `seekg` is fundamental and needs to work correctly before anything else; it probably does and there is some wrong assumption elsewhere. The code is a bit convoluted but it is difficult to suggest a better approach without knowing the file format. Is it binary or text? You are using `strlen` which suggests text but use the binary flag for the output file.  Are headers and records on different lines or is it just one stream of characters?